# Are systems for solving linear systems essentially the same?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that systems of the form

$\left(\begin{matrix}x'\\y'\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}a &b\\c&d\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)$

can be solved like

$\overset{\rightarrow}{x} = \overset{\rightarrow}{v_1}e^{\lambda_1t}+\overset{\rightarrow}{v_2}e^{\lambda_2t}$

where $\overset{\rightarrow}{v_i}$ are the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. First of all I want to know whether or not this generalises to $n$ dimensions.

I do also know that IVPs of the form

$x' = Ax, x(0) = x_0$

have the following solution

$x(t) = \exp(tA)\cdot x_0.$

Are these two solutions (at least for $n=2$) the same? I would say so. $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is Lipschitz and therefore as stated by Picard-Lindelöf theorem the IVP has a unique solution.

Thank you!

Comment: In the first solution you forgot the constants for each term on the right side